# First "ImageView", second "RelativeLayout" - works, but first "RelativeLayout", second "ImageView" - doesn't

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to use show first buttons and only than a picture. But my app can't be started.

This is works:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/make_photo_again"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/make_photo_again_label"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit_photo_label"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

..but if I place "Image" under "RelativeLayout" the app doesn't work.

Really don't know what to do with it..

Could you tell me, why?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you have the height and width of your image set to fill_parent instead of wrap_content?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Just saying "It doesn't work" doesn't point us to any errors you may be getting.

Comment: You want your imageview at the bottom or at the top...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this code in xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/make_photo_again"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Save"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Cancel"
             />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.7"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_box_mytime" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works good! And I've forgot to add android:contentDescription="" to <ImageView/>.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you place your imageview at the beginning of your relative layout just above the buttons then imageview will be at the back side and button will be on the imageview.

If you place your imageview at the end of your relative layout just below two buttons then imageview will be at the front and it will hide your buttons.....

Answer (score 0):

Your XML doesn't look wrong. What errors are you getting.  Please describe.